# Using WMS XML in gdal.Translate()

Tags: python, gdal, wms, gdal-translate, xml

I am using `gdal.Translate()` of Python instead of command line `gdal_translate`. Most of the options in GDAL. Translate are the same with gdal_translate and I could find them easily in `gdal.TranslateOptions` but I am struggling on how to input the WMS XML (https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/wms.html) in the function.

Normally in command line I would do something like this:

```
gdal_translate -of PNG -outsize 512 512 frmt_wms_openstreetmap_tms.xml openstreetmap.png
```

Does someone know how to do the same in `gdal.Translate()`?

Comment: Some Python examples about WMS can be found from https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/autotest/gdrivers/wms.py. Maybe they can give some help for gdal.Translate as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out finally!!!
For me it worked like this:
First I opened the xml file as
`googlemaps_xml=gdal.Open('C:/notebooks_scripts/frmt_wms_googlemaps_satellite_tms.xml')`
and set the output dataset name as `my_image = 'my_image.jpg'`
Then I used the xml as the srcDS (see for more info on the parameteres [osgeo.gdal-module.html#TranslateOptions](https://gdal.org/python/osgeo.gdal-module.html#TranslateOptions)) and added all the other parameters I needed.

```
gdal.Translate(my_image, frmt_wms_googlemaps_satellite_tms, format='JPEG', width=512, height=512, projWin=[ulx, uly, lrx, lry], 
               projWinSRS='EPSG:1234')
```

*ul => Upper Left, lr => Lower right